# Download document created using python-docx

Tags: odoo-10, python-docx

I'm trying to export word report in Odoo, i am using python-docx library,

Code:

```
document = Document()            

records = result

table = document.add_table(rows=0, cols=4,style='Table Grid')  
for att  in records:
    row_cells = table.add_row().cells
    cnt = 0  
    for attdet  in att:
        #row_cells[0].style('text-align: center;vertical-align: middle;') 
        if (cnt == 0):
            row_cells[0].add_paragraph(attdet.serial_no, 'List Bullet')#[0].text = attdet.serial_nobold
            row_cells[1].add_paragraph(attdet.name, 'List Bullet')#[1].text = attdet.name
        else:
            row_cells[2].add_paragraph(attdet.serial_no, 'List Bullet')#.text = attdet.serial_no
            row_cells[3].add_paragraph(attdet.name, 'List Bullet')#.text = attdet.name
        cnt = cnt+1

document.add_page_break()

pdfhttpheaders = [('Content-Type','application/msword')]
return request.make_response(document, headers=pdfhttpheaders)
```

Instead of saving document into folder, i need to download this word document on button click,

I am getting below error,

```
AttributeError: 'JsonRequest' object has no attribute 'make_response'
```

Please anyone guide me to resolve this error.

Comment: What is `type(request)`?

Answer (score 1):

From my point of view you must change the way of produce and get the document specifically where the document is produced and accessed.

The more simpler way to do it I think that it will be to use the button to return an action url dict to redirect the request to a controller with the proper data in the query-string to be able to generate the document as a response, the way you are doing it. Something like:

```
return {
    'type': 'ir.actions.act_url',
    'url': '/report/docx/content/custom',
    'target': 'self',
}
```

Then you could put your code that generate the docx report into a method controller like the following one:

```
from odoo import http, tools, _
from odoo.http import request, Controller

class CustomController(Controller):

    @http.route(['/report/docx/content/custom'], type='http', auth="public")
    def report_docx(self, **kwargs):
        # your code of report generation that use request.make_response
```

Just pass the enough info to the controller using the URL query-string like record id, or any other data that you may need in the controller, but normally the record id will be enough

Comment: Same i did, but the downloaded word document is in read-only, Can you give me idea how to remove the readonly attributes ?

Comment: The read-only nature of your generated document is out of the scope of this question, seems more related to the process of generate it. Did my answer get the file download process successful?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I suspect there's more wrong here than this, but you're going to need to save the document first, perhaps to an `io.BytesIO` stream like this:

```
import io

# ...

docx_stream = io.BytesIO()
document.save(docx_stream)
docx_bytes = docx_stream.getvalue()
```

The `docx_bytes` value is the actual contents of the resulting .docx file, which is what you want in the response. The `document` value is just an in-memory object graph representing the document and has no direct correspondence to a .docx file (other than it can create one using its `.save()` method.

I suspect the response needs to be multipart, but maybe someone who knows more about Odoo can help you with that part.

Also, I believe the content type needs to be `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document` in order to work properly. The one you have ('application/msword') is for the older .doc format (Word 2003 and prior).

I'm not sure what the use of the name `pdfhttpheaders` indicates. This wouldn't have anything to do with the PDF format. I expect `http_headers` would be a more sensible choice for that identifier.